# get the value form input within the list format?

Tags: javascript

I have an input that its value has separator.

```
 <input id="list_id_category" type="hidden" value="29,30,41" name="list_id_category">
```

I try but it does not work

```
document.getElementsByName('list_id_category').value;
```

How can we get the values for this element?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var values = document.getElementById("list_id_category").value.split(",");
```

After which `values` will be an array containing the three numbers.

Your use of the [`getElementsByName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) didn't work because (as implied by the plural) it returns a list (an HTMLCollection) of elements, and that list doesn't have a `.value` property. Use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) instead.

Answer (score 0):

var temp = document.getElementById("list_id_category").value;

Split the returned value using temp.split(',');

Answer (score 0):

```
var valuee=$('#list_id_category').val();
```

I hope this works for your problem.

Comment: Does the OP need to include any external JS libraries for that code to work?